# <button> in IE7

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I tried a few simple jQuery manipulation on `<button>` tags but, for some reasons, didn't work on IE7.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<button class="button">Hello</button>

// jQuery, using v1.4.4
$('button').html('Hello World!');         // Works on Firefox and IE7.
$('button').addClass('another-class');    // Works on Firefox; *not* on IE7.
$('button').wrapInner('<span></span>');   // Works on Firefox; *not* on IE7.
```

Does anyone have any clues about this?

Comment: maybe has something to do with the behaviour described here:  http://www.peterbe.com/plog/button-tag-in-IE ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `button` tag isn't fully supported on IE6 and IE7. It isn't related to jQuery, but about the tag itself, as described here: [What disadvantages are there to the <button> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903453/what-disadvantages-are-there-to-the-button-tag-it-seems-there-are-quite-a-few).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a method named `.innerWrap()` in jQuery.  I see one named `.wrapInner()`.  If I switch your code to `.wrapInner()`, it works for me in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zaaZt/) in IE9 and in IE9 in IE8 and IE7 emulation mode.  I don't have the actual IE7 available to try here, so perhaps part of the issue is the partial support in IE7 for the button tag.

Comment: Thanks for the correction: I just edited the code to `.wrapInner`.