# HTML button that automatically resize based on text without tables

Tags: html, button, autoresize

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="32px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/8052/lefto.png" border="0" />
        </td>
        <td style="background:url(http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/2825/centervw.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; color:#FFFFFF;">
            Press Me Press Me Press Me Press Me Press Me Press Me Press Me Press Me Press Me
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/4676/rightk.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have nice button that auto re-sizes based on length of text in middle table column
try it here http://jsfiddle.net/QaFTc/2/

What i need is to do same without using tables and **centered**.

I tried and i either get not centered or i have to specify the width of button.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you need. If you need just a button you could use <a> tags or <input> if you need to submit a form. You can then style it with CSS.

Comment: I need button like for the navigation menu that looks better than the <input type="button" ...> and i need it to be not image but text. so i can edit it without photoshop for this i need it to auto size background of the text to the length of the text as i shown on the link did you click link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i got: http://jsfiddle.net/nqGX8/

No tables, divs only.  You can use images instead of the colors.

Comment: First time i hear about button tag, again i need it centered.

Comment: The text centered? Or the button centered in it's parent?

Comment: Wrapped with a div (display: inline-block), and text-align: center; on body.  You can center it the same way you would do text, or even have it inline with text.  http://jsfiddle.net/U5gCF/

Comment: gr8 i wanted to go with less tags, but guess there's no way around it.

Comment: i have tried many different ways, and this has been the most consistent in display and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I Added a button using `button` and `span` modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QaFTc/7/)

Comment: Now how do you center it as my link its in the center.

Comment: I modified my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QaFTc/7/. I am using text-align center on button parent(moved button inside a div).

Comment: Problems with button tag: "a potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected", because IE6 submits the html inside of the button, which, in my case, has html tags in it." from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903453/what-disadvantages-are-there-to-the-button-tag-it-seems-there-are-quite-a-fe