# Button merging into list element in IE 7

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a problem with a group of buttons which merge into a list element only in IE 7 or below. So all the buttons appear along with `Title 2` in second li element. Please see html and css below

```
<ul class="tabs">
   <li><a href="#tab1">Title 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab2">Title 2</a></li>
   <span class="button-span">
   <button id="print" title="Print">
   <img alt="Print" src="images/ico-print.png" border="0"/>
   </button>
   <button id="save" title="Save">
   <img alt="Save" src="images/word.gif"/>
   </button>
   </span>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.tabs li {
    background: url('../images/gradient-black.png') repeat-x top left #262626;
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
    border-left: 1px solid #535250;
    border-right: 1px solid #535250;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}

span.button-span {
    margin-right: 35px;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: 1). The buttons should either be inside an li or outside the ul. 2). span is not a block-level element so you either need to make it so using display:block or (preferably) use a div instead. 3). you haven't closed the span.

Comment: what is below IE7? a rabbit hole

Comment: horribly malformed HTML here - take the above suggestion and then return with an updated question. ProTip: When stuff doesn't work run it through a validation service first to knock off obvious mistakes.

Comment: Oops, removed it out of ul, now it's good but it displays below the li I want to display inline with li

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903453/what-disadvantages-are-there-to-the-button-tag-it-seems-there-are-quite-a-fe for a clue, of why it doesn't works properly, also you need to close your span tag like @da5id said

Answer (score 0):

Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/xQ4L9/1/ (use URL http://jsfiddle.net/xQ4L9/1/show/ to view result in IE7)

Steps to fix:

1. Move `button-span` out of `ul` and make it block element.
2. Change corresponding CSS selector from `span.button-span` to `.button-span`
3. Remove `clear:both` for `.button-span`.

Comment: But I want to display the buttons in the same line as the li, not below the li

Comment: They are displayed in the same line (I've tested in IE6 and IE7)